# it always goes first tank

Tags: c, if-statement, random, case

how could I fix this??
it always goes first tank,shouldn't it be random?
or is there any way to code this with strings?
there is 10 tank and we put insert some coins in.
[goes from this pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VpA6.png)

```
    for(k=0;k<=Jsayi-1;k++){
        printf("%d . press smth to continue ",k+1);
//1 ise sola 0 ise sağa düşer
      left=0;

    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {   
        while(rand()%2!=0)
        left++;
}
```

I believe problem is here

```
  if(left=9){
    hzn1++;
    printf("1. tank \n");
  }else if(left=8)
  {hzn2++;
    printf("2. tank \n");
  } else if(left=7)
  {hzn3++;
    printf("3. tank \n");
  }else if(left=6)
  {hzn4++;
    printf("4. tank. \n");
  }else if(left=5)
  {hzn5++;
    printf("5. tank \n");
  }else if(left=4)
  {hzn6++;
    printf("6. tank \n");
  }else if(left=3)
  {hzn7++;
    printf("7. tank\n");
  }else if(left=2)
  {hzn8++;
    printf("8. tank \n");
  } else if(left=1)
  {hzn9++;
    printf("9. tank \n");}
  else if(left=0)
  {hzn10++;
    printf("10. tank \n");
  } }   }
```

where do you guys I am wrong I couldn't find the solution or another algorithm

Comment: Use == instead of = in if condition

Comment: Or better, use `switch-case`. I need to see your whole code to be sure, but I think you can drop the whole idea and use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"=" use to assign variables
example:

```
int x = 15
```

I assign the variable x the value 15.

"==" use to make a condition
example:

```
if (x == 15)
```

This is a condition that check if the variable x is equal to 15 if it does than it
enters the scope of the if statement.